# interpretting お前を倒さずして、消滅などできん！

Tags: parsing

> enemy returns a while after being defeated by the mc
>
> mc「ど、どうしてあなたが……！　この間滅したはずなのに……！？」
>
> enemy「お前を倒さずして、消滅などできん！」
>
> enemy charges....

i will "do it" without beating you, i can't extinguish you, makes no sense in context.

What is he trying to say?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> お前を倒さずして、消滅などできん！
>   I can never vanish without/before defeating you!

- `未然形 + ずして` is a literary way of saying "without ～ing". It's a literary version of ～ないで or ～ずに. See: [闘わずして勝つ vs. 闘わずに勝つ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/58817/5010)
- 消滅する is intransitive.